# Deserialize JSON to object encapsulating list

Tags: java, json, jackson

Because it's a bad habit to leave raw types like `List<String>` on their own in the application I decided to encapsulate it using the following class:

```
public class EncapsulatedList {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> someWords;
    /*
    Some setters, getters and so on
     */
}
```

But it's serialized to:

```
{
  "someWords": [
    "cheese",
    "random cheese",
    "more random cheese"
  ]
}
```

It would be a lot nicer to have it as a plain list like:

```
[
  "cheese",
  "random cheese",
  "more random cheese"
]
```

Is there a clean way to achieve this using Jackson 2 without having to do this explicitly like deserializing the list first and putting it into the encapsulating class?

Comment: Use Jsoup, access the list first and then get the items inside. Read up on the documentation its surprisingly easy to use.

Comment: Don't know whether it is applicable but did you try @JsonUnwrapped?

Comment: Data structures should not be considered inappropriate to use. When you're dealing merely with a list -- just use the list (such wrappers may hurt, and not really encapsulate if you just add simple accessors to your class). When you're working with serialization, you deal with really dumb DTOs, and I don't think it's good to make such a DTO a business object. You might want to use http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html though (not sure it works), or just do `final class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc of `@JsonUnwrapped`:

> Also note that annotation only applies if
>
> - Value is serialized as JSON Object (can not unwrap JSON arrays using this mechanism)

If you don't want to use a `String[]` or `List<String>` directly then you can always deserialize the type yourself, like:

```
class EncapsulatedListDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<EncapsulatedList> {
    // ctor omitted
    public EncapsulatedList deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (node.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode value : node) {
                list.add(value.asText());
            }
        }

        return new EncapsulatedList(list);
    }
}
```

At least that somewhat abstracts the deserialization and calling the setter manually.